# React-Native Speech to Text

Tags: react-native, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, watson-conversation, watson

I am trying to use the Watson Speech to Text API to record audio in a react-native app and then convert the audio to text.

I am having trouble figuring this out and any help would really be appreciated.

I can get the audio recorded but I am having trouble figuring out how to send the file to the backend OR just send directly to the Watson API on the frontend.

The Watson API Cloud library for node has this:

```
      var SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
      var fs = require('fs');

      var speech_to_text = new SpeechToTextV1({
      username: '<username>',
      password: '<password>'
      });

        var params = {
        // From file
        audio: fs.createReadStream('./resources/speech.wav'),
        content_type: 'audio/l16; rate=44100'
         };

       speech_to_text.recognize(params, function(err, res) {
       if (err)
       console.log(err);
       else
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
       });
```

Unfortunately I cannot access 'fs' on the frontend to create Streams. The file gets saved in hidden folder on the client's frontend (which I have the path too)

Eventually I would like to create a stream somehow so I can send the audio as it comes in, to to get converted to text automatically and reduce the speed.

Like this:

```
   fs.createReadStream('./resources/speech.wav')
   .pipe(speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream({ content_type:       'audio/l16; rate=44100' }))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./transcription.txt'));
```

Any idea how to do all this on the frontend with the path of the recorded audio. Any work arounds? Thank you!

Comment: Anuj, unrelated to your question, could you please provide information how you record .wav sound using react-native? I'm having some issues recording .wav sound so if you can provide code snippet how you record a sound it would really help me.
Thanks!

Comment: @vtuhtan you can record .wav files using 'react-native-audio-record'. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-record

Answer (score 2):

React Native supports websockets out of the box: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Watson API supports websockets as part of their Speech to Text API: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/websockets.shtml (See section "Sending audio and receiving recognition results" `websocket.send(blob)`

This seems to be a reasonable solution.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how I would stream the audio file as it changes? Would the socket constantly send as the file gets updates?

Comment: If this is a live recording there is no need for a file, you just push the audio chunks over the websocket as they come from the microphone. On the other hand, if you have an actual file that gets updated then you can read every new audio chunk from the file and push it through the websocket to Watson STT. Hypothesis will come to you asynchronously. Sample code can be found here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/

Comment: @DanielBolanos did you complete this? I was trying to record sound using [react-native-audio](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio/) and then uploading the file. It would be awesome if you could please share how you accomplished it.

Comment: @MatZero do you have any actual javascript code to help us? I am struggling wit this. I am using react-native-audio to record, but I am not able to figure out the watson endpoint uploading.

Comment: @DanielBolanos I got it working on the web, but when I try in react-native, I am having trouble with the file upload. I posted a topic with my code here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/44106529/1828637

Answer (score 1):

I have put together a native module that uses the watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk, and speech to text is implemented.

https://github.com/pwcremin/react-native-watson

You can refer to my code for an example of how to implement it, or just use the module.

The react-native-watson module uses the mic and handles streaming for you:

```
import {SpeechToText} from 'react-native-watson';

SpeechToText.initialize("username", "password")

// will transcribe microphone audio
SpeechToText.startStreaming((error, text) =>
        {
            console.log(text)
        })

SpeechToText.stopStreaming()
```