# Upload a file but set Content-Type

Tags: react-native, speech-to-text, watson

I got Watson Speech-to-Text working on the web. I am now trying to do it on react native but am getting errors on the file upload part.

I am using the HTTPS Watson API. I need to set the `Content-Type` otherwise Watson returns a error response. However in react-native, for the file upload to work, we seem to need to set `'Content-Type'` to `'multipart/form-data'`. Is there anyway to upload a file in react-native while setting Content-Type to `'audio/aac'`?

The error Watson API gives me if I set `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` is:

```
{
    type: "default",
    status: 400,
    ok: false,
    statusText: undefined,
    headers: Object,
    url: "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true",
    _bodyInit: Blob,
    _bodyBlob: Blob
}
```

The response body is:

```
{
   "code_description": "Bad Request", 
   "code": 400, 
   "error": "No JSON object could be decoded"
}
```

Here is my code (full code is here - [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/17f37499e8d11b50c29421667c2f3f88) ):

```
    const ext = 'aac';
    const file_path = '/storage/emulated/0/Music/enter-the-book.aac';
    data.append('file', {
        uri: `file://${file_path}`,
        name: `recording.${ext}`,
        type: `audio/${ext}`
    }, `recording.${ext}`);

    const response = await fetch('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            // 'Content-Type': `audio/${ext}`,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'X-Watson-Authorization-Token': token
        },
        body: data
    });

    console.log('watson-stt::getResults - response:', response);

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        const error = await response.text();
        throw new Error(`Got bad response "status" (${response.status}) from Watson Speach to Text server, error: "${error}"`);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error I get when I set `'Content-Type': 'audio/aac'`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for multipart requests](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/#recognize_sessionless_mp) the request should be:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}"
--header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
--form metadata="{
  \"part_content_type\":\"audio/flac\",
  \"timestamps\":true,
  \"continuous\":true}"
--form upload="@audio-file1.flac"
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
```

So the `content-type` should be `multipart/form-data`, you can specify aac as `"part_content_type": "audio/aac"`.

The big problem you have is that `audio/aac` is not in supported [formats](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/input.html#formats). You might probably need another codec.

Comment: Oh shoot. Thanks very much @Nikolay ! I will try to find a converter. It doesn't seem any of the iOS or Android audio formats are supported by Bluemix. Encodings supported on iOS: `lpcm, ima4, aac, MAC3, MAC6, ulaw, alaw, mp1, mp2, alac, amr` Encodings supported on Android: `aac, aac_eld, amr_nb, amr_wb, he_aac, vorbis`. The only common between the two was `aac` so I was using that haha

Comment: Hi @Noitidart , the Watson STT service does support some of those codecs, for example it supports `ulaw` for iOS or `vorbis` for Android. Please see this link: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/input.html

Comment: @DanielBolanos oh my gosh awesome!!! Thanks so much for sharing that with me Daniel! I thought none of those were supported so was looking all around for how to convert from AAC. Will try those out and let you know how it goes! :)

Comment: @DanielBolanos I was having a triky time on Android, it seems there are two types of `vorbis`: `ogg` and `webm`. I can't figure out which one Android is giving me. Do you know by chance? I know that Google Chrome gives the `webm` version and that doesn't work with watson - https://stackoverflow.com/q/44127061/1828637

Comment: Hi @Noitidart, The IBM Watson STT service supports vorbis inside both webm and ogg containers, so webm + vorbis should work, if that is not working for you, what error do you get? 

From the documentation (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/index.html): 

Audio formats: Transcribes Free Lossless Audio Codec (FLAC), Linear 16-bit Pulse-Code Modulation (PCM), Waveform Audio File Format (WAV), Ogg format with the Opus or Vorbis codec, Web Media (WebM) format with the Opus or Vorbis codec, mu-law (or u-law) audio data, or basic audio.

Comment: Thansk very much Daniel, that's odd though, if it is  supported how come it wouldn't work in Chrome. By default it gives webm + vorbis I thought. On Android I actually jumped the gun to upload to IBM, I am actually still having issues recording I have to fix that first before upload haha

Answer (score 3):

Thanks so much to DanielBolanos and NikolayShmyrev this is the solution I used:

This code is for iOS so I recorded the audio as `blah.ulaw` BUT the part_content_type is `aduio/mulaw;rate=22050` this is very important to use `mulaw` even though file ext is `ulaw`. An interesting note: I couldn't play the `blah.ulaw` file on my macOS desktop.

Also note that you MUST NOT set `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` this will destroy the `boundary`.

Also Bluemix requires rate in the part_content_type for mulaw

```
const body = new FormData();
let metadata = {
    part_content_type: 'audio/mulaw;rate=22050'  // and notice "mulaw" here, "ulaw" DOES NOT work here
};
body.append('metadata', JSON.stringify(metadata));
body.append('upload', {
    uri: `file://${file_path}`,
    name: `recording.ulaw`, // notice the use of "ulaw" here
    type: `audio/ulaw` // and here it is also "ulaw"
});

const response = await fetch('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' // DO NOT SET THIS!! It destroys the boundary and messes up the request
        'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}`)}`
    },
    body
});
```