# MediaRecorder working in Firefox, but not in Chrome for Speech-to-Text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, speech-to-text, watson

Here is a jsfiddle of the working code:  https://jsfiddle.net/Noitidart/z5dqpe8r/

If I load up the fiddle in Firefox it works perfect. It records the audio, sends it to watson and gets the results. However in Chrome, when it sends it to watson it gets an error. How can I get it to work in Google Chrome?

I based it on the code from the documentation here - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/input.html#formats - under `audio/webm` section it has this:

> For JavaScript code that shows how to capture audio from a microphone in a Chrome browser and encode it into a WebM data stream, see [jsbin.com/hedujihuqo/edit?js,console](https://jsbin.com/hedujihuqo/edit?js,console). Note that the code does not submit the captured audio to the service.

That jsbin linked is here - https://jsbin.com/hedujihuqo/edit?js,console

It works perfectly in Firefox. However it is not working in Chrome. In Firefox I actually needed to use `audio/ogg`. The jsbin from the docs say to use `auio/webm` for Google Chrome.

Here is my upload code:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', blob, 'recording.' + file_ext);
let results_res = await fetch('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/' + file_ext,
        'X-Watson-Authorization-Token': token
    },
    body: data
});
```

Any ideas on why it's not working in Chrome?

Comment: Hi the problem is not with the chrome. The problem is with watson. Watson is not able to transcode the data stream

Comment: Thanks @karthick - but the example on the docs says specifically for it work in chrome that we should set it to `webm`. Shouldn't this make it work in chrome per the docs?

Comment: It's kind of confusing. the document does say it supports webm. But all the examples they have looks like they don't. Content types supported
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/speech-to-text/content-type.js

Comment: So I did a bit of tests ; Everyone knows that chrome's files are [missing a lot of metadata](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012), so I thought that fixing the file with ffmpeg would do. It doesn't... I tried to send an FF recorded file from chrome : worked. I tried to convert an chrome recorded file to webm/vorbis : didn't worked. The FF file to webm/OPUS ? didn't worked. Chrome file to ogg/opus ? Worked. All this tend to say that despite the fact their docs say they do support webm/audio, well they don't...

Comment: Oh thank you very much @Kaiido ! I will test out ogg/opus tonight on Chrome! :)

Comment: All these tests were passed to ffmpeg for file conversions, iirc chrome doesnt record in ogg for some odd reasons.

Comment: @kaiido I'm not able to get the MediaRecorder to startup in Chrome if i set `mimeType` to ogg vorbis or opus in Chrome. `recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });` - http://i.imgur.com/RBhfY6v.png - you mentioned "Chrome file to ogg/opus" worked, may you please add some more details :)

Comment: I was also looking at how they handle it in Bluemix's "browser" version - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk - but I can't find the keyword "MediaRecorder" when I search. I was trying to find a javascript converter for `audio/webm` to `audio/ogg`.

Comment: @Noitidart, As I said, I used ffmpeg to do the conversions between file formats, then I sent directly the files to BlueMix, without using MediaRecorder anymore. Chrome doesn't support recording as `audio/ogg`, which sounds weird to me but this API and its implementations still surprise me every day ;-) But I think the link provided by karthick is up to date and simply means that BlueMix doesn't support media recorded by Chrome. And if you've got an webm => ogg converter, then you'd probably be able to provide an real fix for [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012)

Comment: Ohhhh I get it @Kaiido - thanks very much for putting that effort in to help. They advertise their JS SDK here specifically for the browser - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk - I wonder if that excludes Crhome

Comment: @Noitidart, they are converting the mic-stream to raw L16 wav : https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/speech-to-text/webaudio-l16-stream.js They don't use MediaRecorder. Could be a workaround for you, or simply use this SDK ;-)

Comment: Thanks very much @Kaiido ! I will definitely use that as a workaround thanks very much! I actually can't use SDK because I am using this in non-node and non-browser environments so the SDK doesn't work. :(